# Turtle's shape as images

Tags: netlogo, turtle-graphics

I am new to NetLogo. Is there a way to set the turtle's shape with my own images?

The idea is to rewrite the library Pacman model in the way that agents would have my friends' faces as shapes.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Shapes Editor for this:
https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/shapes.html

Comment: I read the documentation. Can you import images (.png, .jpgs) ? I thought you could only draw your own.

Comment: Ah, I read your question too quickly.  See
https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/509

Answer (score 2):

You can do fairly sophisticated drawing with NetLogo's Turtle Shape Editor but NetLogo itself doesn't know how to import external graphic files as shapes.

There exists, however, a **NLBitmapSprites** extension, written by Thomas Dickerson, that *might* be exactly what you are looking:

https://github.com/elfprince13/NLBitmapSprites

I have never tried it, and don't know if it will work with the latest version of NetLogo, but there is a pretty nice [demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxwuj0xVsgo) linked from the extension's page.